# How to delete some lines in streamplot

Tags: plotting

my name is Michael and im new to this Forum, so sorry for any misbehavior (also english is not my native language).

My Question:

I have a given (quite difficult) electrical field and i want to make a Streamplot.

This are my Functions:

```
Ey1 := -\[Sigma] (Log[
  a - x + Sqrt[(-a + x)^2 + (a - y)^2 + (z - d)^2]] + 
 Log[-a + x + 
   Sqrt[(-a + x)^2 + (a + y)^2 + (z - d)^2]]) + \[Sigma] (Log[-a -
    x + Sqrt[(a + x)^2 + (a - y)^2 + (z - d)^2]] + 
 Log[a + x + Sqrt[(a + x)^2 + (a + y)^2 + (z - d)^2]])

Ey2 := \[Sigma] (Log[
      a - x + Sqrt[(-a + x)^2 + (a - y)^2 + (z + d)^2]] + 
     Log[-a + x + 
       Sqrt[(-a + x)^2 + (a + y)^2 + (z + d)^2]]) - \[Sigma] (Log[-a -
        x + Sqrt[(a + x)^2 + (a - y)^2 + (z + d)^2]] + 
     Log[a + x + Sqrt[(a + x)^2 + (a + y)^2 + (z + d)^2]])

Ez1 := \[Sigma] (ArcTan[((a - x) (-a + y))/((z - 
         d) Sqrt[(a - x)^2 + (-a + y)^2 + (z - d)^2])] + 
     ArcTan[((a + x) (-a + y))/((z - 
         d) Sqrt[(a + x)^2 + (-a + y)^2 + (z - 
          d)^2])]) - \[Sigma] (ArcTan[((a - x) (a + y))/((z - 
         d) Sqrt[(a - x)^2 + (a + y)^2 + (z - d)^2])] + 
     ArcTan[((a + x) (a + y))/((z - 
         d) Sqrt[(a + x)^2 + (a + y)^2 + (z - d)^2])])

Ez2 := -\[Sigma] (ArcTan[((a - x) (-a + y))/((z + 
         d) Sqrt[(a - x)^2 + (-a + y)^2 + (z + d)^2])] + 
     ArcTan[((a + x) (-a + y))/((z + 
         d) Sqrt[(a + x)^2 + (-a + y)^2 + (z + 
          d)^2])]) + \[Sigma] (ArcTan[((a - x) (a + y))/((z + 
         d) Sqrt[(a - x)^2 + (a + y)^2 + (z + d)^2])] + 
     ArcTan[((a + x) (a + y))/((z + 
         d) Sqrt[(a + x)^2 + (a + y)^2 + (z + d)^2])])
```

This is my Plot so far:

```
Show[StreamPlot[{Ez1 + Ez2, Ey1 + Ey2} /. {a -> 10, 
x -> 0, \[Sigma] -> 1, d -> 2}, {z, -15, 15}, {y, -15, 15}],Graphics[{Red, Line[{{-2, -10}, {-2, 10}}], Red, Line[{{2, -10}, {2, 10}}]}]]
```

[image: Streamplot]

As you can see i have highlightet some lines, that does not start on the plate.

Is there any way to get rid of this lines ?

I tried to work with DeleteCase, but it was not successful.

Thx, Michael

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When such things matter it might be easier to specify the "stream points," instead of fixing what the default setting does:

```
sp = Join[
   Table[{-3, y}, {y, -10, 9, 1}],
   Table[{3, y}, {y, -10, 9, 1}],
   Table[{0, y}, {y, -10, 9, 1}]
   ];

Show[
 StreamPlot[
  {Ez1 + Ez2, Ey1 + Ey2} /. {a -> 10, x -> 0, \[Sigma] -> 1, d -> 2},
  {z, -15, 15}, {y, -15, 15}, StreamPoints -> sp
  ],
 Graphics[{Red, Line[{{-2, -10}, {-2, 10}}], Red, Line[{{2, -10}, {2, 10}}]}]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]