# StreamPlot symmetry

Tags: plotting

I have a given (quite difficult) electrical field and i want to make a Streamplot.

This are my Functions:

```
Ey1 := -σ (Log[
  a - x + Sqrt[(-a + x)^2 + (a - y)^2 + (z - d)^2]] + 
 Log[-a + x + 
   Sqrt[(-a + x)^2 + (a + y)^2 + (z - d)^2]]) + σ (Log[-a -
    x + Sqrt[(a + x)^2 + (a - y)^2 + (z - d)^2]] + 
 Log[a + x + Sqrt[(a + x)^2 + (a + y)^2 + (z - d)^2]])

Ey2 := σ (Log[
      a - x + Sqrt[(-a + x)^2 + (a - y)^2 + (z + d)^2]] + 
     Log[-a + x + 
       Sqrt[(-a + x)^2 + (a + y)^2 + (z + d)^2]]) - σ (Log[-a -
        x + Sqrt[(a + x)^2 + (a - y)^2 + (z + d)^2]] + 
     Log[a + x + Sqrt[(a + x)^2 + (a + y)^2 + (z + d)^2]])

Ez1 := σ (ArcTan[((a - x) (-a + y))/((z - 
         d) Sqrt[(a - x)^2 + (-a + y)^2 + (z - d)^2])] + 
     ArcTan[((a + x) (-a + y))/((z - 
         d) Sqrt[(a + x)^2 + (-a + y)^2 + (z - 
          d)^2])]) - σ (ArcTan[((a - x) (a + y))/((z - 
         d) Sqrt[(a - x)^2 + (a + y)^2 + (z - d)^2])] + 
     ArcTan[((a + x) (a + y))/((z - 
         d) Sqrt[(a + x)^2 + (a + y)^2 + (z - d)^2])])

Ez2 := -σ (ArcTan[((a - x) (-a + y))/((z + 
         d) Sqrt[(a - x)^2 + (-a + y)^2 + (z + d)^2])] + 
     ArcTan[((a + x) (-a + y))/((z + 
         d) Sqrt[(a + x)^2 + (-a + y)^2 + (z + 
          d)^2])]) + σ (ArcTan[((a - x) (a + y))/((z + 
         d) Sqrt[(a - x)^2 + (a + y)^2 + (z + d)^2])] + 
     ArcTan[((a + x) (a + y))/((z + 
         d) Sqrt[(a + x)^2 + (a + y)^2 + (z + d)^2])])
```

This is my first Plot:

```
sp3 = Join[Table[{-2.1, y}, {y, -9, 9, 1}], 
   Table[{2.1, y}, {y, -9, 9, 1}], Table[{1.34, y}, {y, -9, 9, 1}]];

Show[StreamPlot[{Ez1 + Ez2, Ey1 + Ey2} /. {a -> 10, 
    x -> 0, \[Sigma] -> 1, d -> 2}, {z, -15, 15}, {y, -15, 15}, 
  StreamScale -> Full, StreamStyle -> {Gray, Arrowheads[0.02]}, 
  StreamPoints -> sp3],
 Graphics[{Black, Thick, Line[{{-2, -10}, {-2, 10}}], Black, Thick, 
   Line[{{2, -10}, {2, 10}}]}]]
```

[image]

This is my second Plot:

```
   sp1 = Join[Table[{-2.1, y}, {y, -9, 9, 1}],Table[{2.1, y}, {y, -9, 9, 1}]];
   sp2 = Table[{-1.9, y}, {y, -9, 9, 1}];

Show[StreamPlot[{Ez1 + Ez2, Ey1 + Ey2} /. {a -> 10, 
    x -> 0, \[Sigma] -> 1, d -> 2}, {z, -15, 15}, {y, -15, 15}, 
  StreamScale -> Full, StreamStyle -> {Gray, Arrowheads[0.02]}, 
  StreamPoints -> sp1],
 Graphics[{Black, Thick, Line[{{-2, -10}, {-2, 10}}], Black, Thick, 
   Line[{{2, -10}, {2, 10}}]}], 
 StreamPlot[{Ez1 + Ez2, Ey1 + Ey2} /. {a -> 10, x -> 0, \[Sigma] -> 1,
     d -> 2}, {z, -2, 2}, {y, -10, 10}, StreamScale -> None, 
  StreamStyle -> {Gray, Arrowheads[0.02]}, StreamPoints -> sp2]]
```

[image]

As you can see, on the second plot, i have two Streamplots, one for the outside of the plate and one for the inside.

The reason for this is, as you can see in the first Streamplot on the highlighted spots, where i used only one one Streamplot, it seems that close to the plate on the inside, ther are no lines anymore.

On the Second Plot i can place the manual StreamPoints on the inside very close to the Plate (-1.9), so it looks totally symmetric.

On the first Plot i cant place the manual StreamPlots not closer than 1.34, otherwise all lines on the inside vanishs.

Basicly Teh electrical field functions are in both cases the same, its just a second StreamPlot on in use. But with this second StreamPlot i get a total different behavior in the inside of the plates.

Does somebody know why, and is it possilbe to plot it like the second plot, but with only one Streamplot ?

(related topic: [How to delete some lines in streamplot](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/134126/how-to-delete-some-lines-in-streamplot))

Comment: You can plot multiple vector fields in one plot, you can also use `Epilog` to add your lines.

Comment: `StreamPlot` will automatically adjust your specified stream points. In other words, it takes them as a suggestion only.  For absolute control use `NDSolve`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To give an example of what I meant in my comment.

```
params = {a -> 10, x -> 0, σ -> 1, d -> 2};

ode = {z'[t], y'[t]} == ({Ez1 + Ez2, Ey1 + Ey2} /. {v : y | z :> v[t]} /. 
    params);
psol = ParametricNDSolveValue[{ode, {z[0], y[0]} == {a, b},
   WhenEvent[Abs[z[t]] > 15 || Abs[y[t]] > 15, "StopIntegration"],
   WhenEvent[Abs[Abs@z[t] - 2] < 0.01 && Abs[y[t]] < 10, "StopIntegration"]},
  {z, y}, {t, -100, 100}, {a, b}, 
  Method -> {"ExplicitRungeKutta", "StiffnessTest" -> True}, 
  MaxSteps -> 10000, MaxStepSize -> 0.1];

sols = psol @@@ sp3; // AbsoluteTiming
(*  {0.402537, Null}  *)

Graphics[{
  Gray, Arrowheads[0.02],
  Arrow[
   Transpose@Through[#["ValuesOnGrid"]] & /@ sols[[1 ;; -1]]
   ],
  {Black, Thick, Line[{{-2, -10}, {-2, 10}}], Black, Thick, 
   Line[{{2, -10}, {2, 10}}]}
  },
 PlotRange -> 15, Frame -> True, PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.02]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Hi Michael E2, at the time you suggested me this solution, the goal of project the chanched and i wasnt focused on this soution any more, because i was suddenly busy with tother golas. due to this project, today it is once again crucial to get precise stream points. i didnt hesitate to try your suggested example and modifiy it for my new problem. it was very helpful and gives me a very nice plot. so i want to say, thank you very much.

Comment: Hi @Mike, you're welcome. I'm it helped.

Comment: @Michael E2 Hi. The code throws an error during execution. What is `sp` in `ics = Show[sp, Graphics[{Red, PointSize@Large,  Point@Fold[Drop, sp3, {{38}, {20}}]}]]; `?

Comment: @lotus2019 It's a stream plot. Maybe one of the OP's, or an attempt at alignment. Probably. I don't remember. It's also irrelevant, so I removed it. Probably was accidentally left in the code.

Comment: @Michael E2 Thanks a lot!