# Controlling StreamPoints

Tags: plotting

I have to plot the Electrical Field of half infinity charged plates.

The mathematical Function to this is:

```
Efeld[x_, 
  z_] := {\[Sigma] (Log[x^2 + (z - d)^2] - 
     Log[x^2 + (z + d)^2]), \[Sigma] (\[Pi] Sign[z - d] + 
     2 ArcTan[x/(z - d) ] - \[Pi] Sign[z + d] - 2 ArcTan[x/(z + d) ])}
```

This are my StreamPlots:

```
strp = Table[{y, 0}, {y, -5, 7, .5}];

additionalstrp = Join[strp,
   {{6.`, 4.8}, {6.`, 5.6},
    {6.`, 6.4}, {6.`, 7.15},
    {6.`, 7.9}, {6.8`, 8},
    {6.`, -4.8}, {6.`, -5.6},
    {6.`, -6.4}, {6.`, -7.15},
    {6.`, -7.9}, {6.8`, -8},
    {-4.5`, 7.6}, {-4.9`, 8.},
    {-4.5`, -7.6}, {-4.9`, -8.},
    {0.125, \[Pi]}}];
```

This are some Parameters:

```
plotsizeminx := 5
plotsizemaxx := 7
plotsizeminy := 8.5
plotsizemaxy := 8.5
```

This is the Plot:

```
 strplot =StreamPlot[
  Efeld[-x, -y] /. {\[Sigma] -> 1, 
    d -> \[Pi]}, {x, -plotsizeminx, +plotsizemaxx}, {y, -plotsizeminy,
    plotsizemaxy}, 
  Epilog -> {Black, Thickness[0.01], 
    Line[{{-plotsizeminx, Pi}, {0, Pi}}], 
    Line[{{-plotsizeminx, -Pi}, {0, -Pi}}]}, StreamScale -> None, 
  StreamStyle -> {Thickness[0.002], Black}, 
  StreamPoints -> additionalstrp, PlotRangePadding -> -0.3, 
  AspectRatio -> 1/1.5]
```

This is picture of the plot:

[image]

As you can see i have highligted some areas where the streaming arrows stop "too early".

Mainly i defined the Streampoints depending on the horizontal symmetry axis, so that it looks simular to another picture.

Even tho i have definde the StreamPoints by myself i do not have enough control to get rid of this "gaps" at the and of a "StreamLine".

Do you have any Idea how to get rid of this gaps.

Thank you.

Comment: have already found a solution

Comment: Please write up your solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so some time ago a other user helped me with a similar problem. at least i took this solution and manipulated it to fit to the acutal problem.

```
strp2 = Table[{y, 0}, {y, -4.5, 15, .5}]

params = {\[Sigma] -> 1, d -> \[Pi]};

ode = {x'[t], y'[t]} == (Efeld[x, y] /. {v : y | x :> v[t]} /. params)

{Derivative[1][x][t], 
  Derivative[1][y][t]} == {Log[x[t]^2 + (-\[Pi] - y[t])^2] - 
   Log[x[t]^2 + (\[Pi] - y[t])^2], -2 ArcTan[x[t]/(-\[Pi] - y[t])] + 
   2 ArcTan[
     x[t]/(\[Pi] - y[t])] + \[Pi] Sign[-\[Pi] - 
      y[t]] - \[Pi] Sign[\[Pi] - y[t]]}

psol = ParametricNDSolveValue[
   {
    ode,
    {x[0], y[0]} == {a, b},
    WhenEvent[
     Abs[x[t]] < plotsizemaxx || Abs[x[t]] > plotsizeminx || 
      Abs[y[t]] < plotsizemaxy || Abs[y[t]] > plotsizeminy, 
     "StopIntegration"], 
    WhenEvent[Abs[y[t] - \[Pi]] < 0.01 && x[t] < 0, "StopIntegration"]
    },
   {x, y},
   {t, -100, 100},
   {a, b},
   Method -> {"ExplicitRungeKutta", "StiffnessTest" -> True},
   MaxSteps -> 10000,
   MaxStepSize -> 0.01];

sols = psol @@@ strp2; // AbsoluteTiming
(*{25.573434066961003`,Null}*)
```

its a numerical solution. so i totally bypass the function StreamPlot. i apply this method to every streampoint so i get every line upto the detail needed. with Graphics[] you can plot them alltogether.

```
Graphics[
 {Black, Thickness[0.002], 
  Line[Transpose@Through[#["ValuesOnGrid"]] & /@ sols], {Black, 
   Thickness[0.01], Line[{{-plotsizeminx, \[Pi]}, {0, \[Pi]}}], Black,
    Thickness[0.01], Line[{{-plotsizeminx, -\[Pi]}, {0, -\[Pi]}}]}}
 , PlotRange -> {{-plotsizeminx, +plotsizemaxx}, {-plotsizeminy, 
    plotsizemaxy}}]
```

at this point i´m no expert to this (acutually im having a mathematica lecture right now, until now i had to learn this by myself), so i hope this is helpful.

Comment: I suppose you mean [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/134260/4999)? (When the help came from Q&A on this site, the common practice is to include a link. And often people link to references off-site, too.)

Comment: yes, i meant this one ^^ thx again :)