# How can I reproduce this StreamPlot?

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

I am trying to reproduce this plot:

[image]

This comes from the $\beta$-functions of two coupling $g_1$ and $g_2$, which are

[image]

for the case $N=1$ and $\varepsilon=1$.

I tried to use `StreamPlot`, but the result looks very different:

```
{-(g1^1/2) + (\[DoubleStruckCapitalN] + 6)/(2 (4 \[Pi])^2) g1^3 + 
    1/(4 \[Pi])^4 (-(3/4) (4 \[DoubleStruckCapitalN] + 3) g1^5 - 
       2 g1^3 g2 + (g1^1 g2^2)/12), -g2 + 
    1/(4 \[Pi])^2 (3 g2^2 + 2 \[DoubleStruckCapitalN] g1^2 g2 - 
       12 \[DoubleStruckCapitalN] g1^4) + 
    1/(4 \[Pi])^4 (96 \[DoubleStruckCapitalN] g1^6 + 
       7 \[DoubleStruckCapitalN] g1^4 g2 - 
       3 \[DoubleStruckCapitalN] g1^2 g2^2 - 
       17/3 g2^3)} /. \[DoubleStruckCapitalN] -> 1 /. g1 -> g1^2
StreamPlot[%, {g1, -1, 5}, {g2, -4, 9}]
```

[image]

Why is that?

**EDIT:**

I have made some progress with this code, inspired by [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/134134/streamplot-symmetry):

```
ode = {g1'[t], 
    g2'[t]} == ({-(g1/2) + (\[DoubleStruckCapitalN] + 6)/(
          2 (4 \[Pi])^2) g1^3, -g2 + 
         1/(4 \[Pi])^2 (3 g2^2 + 2 \[DoubleStruckCapitalN] g1^2 g2 - 
            12 \[DoubleStruckCapitalN] g1^4)} /. \
\[DoubleStruckCapitalN] -> 1 /. {v : g1 | g2 :> v[t]} /. params);
sp3 = Join[Table[{x, 0 - 2}, {x, -2, 2, .5}], 
   Table[{x, 0 + 2}, {x, -2, 0, .5}], {{3, 25}, {3, 15}}, 
   Table[{x, (16 \[Pi]^2)/3 - 1}, {x, -2, 4, 1}], 
   Table[{x, (16 \[Pi]^2)/3 + 1}, {x, -2, 4, 1}], {{-1.5, 70}}, {{-1, 
     45}}, {{1, 40}, {2, 40}}, {{-1, 30}}, 
   Table[{x, (48 \[Pi]^2)/7 + 2}, {x, 2, 8, .75}], {{5, 20}}, {{4.5, 
     0}}, {{5, 75}}];
psol = ParametricNDSolveValue[{ode, {g1[0], g2[0]} == {a, b}, 
    WhenEvent[-2 < g1[t] < 6 || -20 < g2[t] < 80, 
     "StopIntegration"]}, {g1, g2}, {t, -100, 100}, {a, b}, 
   Method -> {"ExplicitRungeKutta", "StiffnessTest" -> True}, 
   MaxSteps -> 10000, MaxStepSize -> 0.1];
sols = psol @@@ sp3;
Show[{Graphics[{Gray, Arrowheads[Table[.03, {10}]], Thickness[.0025], 
    Arrow[Transpose@Through[#["ValuesOnGrid"]] & /@ sols[[1 ;; -1]]]},
    PlotRange -> {{-2, 6}, {-20, 80}}, Frame -> True, 
   AspectRatio -> 1, GridLines -> Automatic, 
   PlotRangeClipping -> True, 
   Epilog -> {Blue, PointSize@Large, Point[{0, 0}]}]}]
```

I obtain this:

[image]

My (new) problem is that I only have arrows along the lines that have starting and end points. Any idea how I could solve this problem?

Comment: If the marked dots are equilibria, then `N@Solve[vf == 0, {g1, g2}]` suggests you have a different vector field.

Comment: Something I remember from Trott's Graphics Guidebook. Suppose I want to  do contour plots in different coordinate systems. Let's say I have f[x,y] and want to plot it in {r,\[Phi]}. I need to apply {x,y}->{r,\[Phi]} twice, first on the function being plotted, then on the result. The first one yields f[r,\[Phi]], which I evaluate on the r-\[Phi] grid. The results are on the r-\[Phi] grid, which looks Cartesian, not polar. The second transformation maps me to the appropriate grid. Something similar may be happening in your case

Comment: If I keep the two leading terms for each $\beta$-functions, I find $3$ (positive) fixed points as expected but indeed at very different values than what they show on the plot. For example, one is visible by setting the range to {g1,-1,1} and {g2,52,54}. Even if I accept that the values don't match the plot, I do not manage to obtain a StreamPlot that shows these fixed points in a readable way. Any suggestion?

Comment: Particularly problematic is the point at $g_1 \sim 4.74964, g_2 \sim 67.6773$ (after truncating as in my previous comment). Even zooming in that part of the plot, it is very hard to identify the point visually. I tried to rescale $g_k \to (4\pi)^2 g_k$, but then I lose the points all together, even the ones on the $g_1 = 0$ axis.